# How do I debug a Rabbitmq diagnostic error about missing bindings

Tags: rabbitmq

We've got an error in Rabbitmq diagnostics that states:

> You have more incoming than delivered messages. Not routing all
>   messages might indicate missing bindings.

Just wondering how I can debug and fix this or even if it's a big deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is to use an [alternate exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) configuration.
Idea is that any message that cannot be routed through the "normal" exchange will be given to its alternate exchange.
For the alternate exchange, define a fanout exchange bound to a single queue (lets call it notroutedq).

The moment you see a message in the notroutedq, you know you have indeed missing bindings, and checking the message properties, you can see which routing key the message has, and adapt the binding to ensure proper processing of this type of message.